# Name of notation used in conjunction with XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm looking for the **name for this style** of literal, containing the full namespace URI in curly brackets followed by the identifier name.

```
{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dateTime
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question, I've never seen that form of notation before.
A quick google for "xml namepsace in curly braces" threw up this site: http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

It looks like 'universal name' or 'extended data model' might be the terms you're looking for.
The author of the linked article also suggests that the { } form isn't used because it's incompatible with XML 1.0.

Comment: Thanks! I guess `universal name` is the closest we can possibly get.

Answer (score 10):

It's a notation introduced by James Clark and quite commonly used; for example this is how QNames are passed as parameter names in the JAXP API specification. It's not standardized, and it's probably most often referred to as "Clark notation".